# Best setup to work with amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a website which gets backup from different social media services and then stores the data on server and then that is displayed on my website. content includes, videos, images, and text data.

Currently i am using an EC2 instance with RDS and EBS. Data is stored in EBS Volumes, But as the amount of the data is big enough more than 1 TB and that is increasing. Every time my EBS volume gets filled i attach another volume.

Then i added S3 to my Setup. Cron jobs runs and stores data on S3 and the EC2 instance displays data from the S3. I am using PHP SDK for this purpose.

The problem which i am facing is that the S3 is very slow in my current setup. 
Please suggest whether my setup is good or i need some change in my setup and the other way how can i speedup S3. or i should opt some other way to my setup.
EC2 instance is large reserved instance running CentOS.

I have listened some about the [S3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) that mount S3 bucket to Ec2 as a volume. Is this a good choice, as when i mounted S3 Bucket to Ec2 instance the transfer rate was very slow.

I am new to the AWS. My users does not access files directly from S3, but they access through my website which is running on EC2 Instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RDS is a good choice for storing metadata such as tags, comments and other relevant information about your multimedia files. S3 is good for storing static content such as Video, Audio and Pictures. I think your approach with RDS and S3 is good enough.

EBS backed instances are good for persistence. If you store your metadata on RDS and static content on S3, the only reason why you should use EBS backed EC2 instances is that you have some configuration files which are unversioned right now. If that's not the case, assuming that your configuration is checked into version control and can be pulled on-demand for a fresh instance every time, then you might want to ditch EBS volumes in favor of ephemeral storage. That may give you some performance boost, nothing significant though.

Regarding your concern with S3's latency, yes, S3 is slow. While all your writes may happen directly to S3, I would highly recommend that you set up [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/#functionality) for your S3 buckets and let your website consume multimedia content from the CloudFront. CloudFront is a Content Delivery Network (CDN) which works with disk volumes (EBS backed or ephemeral) as well as with S3. Setting it up would take not more than a few minutes. CloudFront also supports streaming media files over [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol). You may need a library like [GPAC](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/) for hinting multimedia files to make them streamable if not being done already. You might then want to consider creating one distribution for Video/Audio files for streaming and another distribution for Images, Javascript, Stylesheets and other text files.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For faster getting and uploading files from Amazon S3 I use `batch()` [found here](http://www.chrisjhill.co.uk/article/amazon-s3-batch-uploading-upload-stream).

Also you can use [cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) for faster getting files. I think 9gag uses cloudfront also..